# Swift & Objective C protocols: throwing function declaration

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-protocol

I have a Obj C protocol in a library...

```
@protocol DataWriter <NSObject>

- (void) writeData:(NSData*)data;

@end
```

...that I would like to use in Swift 3.1:

```
class Streamer: NSObject, DataWriter {

    ...

    // MARK: - DataWriter

    func write(_ data: Data) throws {
        // write data
        throw NSError(domain: "", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

This works fine without the error throwing, but here the compiler complains that `Candidate throws, but protocol does not allow it`, which I totally get. How would I have to change the protocol so I can throw an error in `writeData`?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe add an `error:(NSError **)error` parameter to the end of the signature?

Comment: @Eimantas yes, and it also needs to return a bool in the protocol, but not in the swift implementation.
`- (BOOL) writeData:(NSData*)data error:(NSError **)error;`seems to work.